# Delete all but one file loop with bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, del

I have a loop in a batch file to delete all but one file in a directory (Windows 7).  But it hangs up because it still sends the commands to the screen, even though I'd thought I'd suppressed it.  Here is the command I'm using:

```
for %i in (*) do if not %i == UPDATE.BAT del /s %i >nul 2>&1
```

Tested my batch script, log shows it stops right at this command.  Tested the command at the command line, outputs the "del /s file.ext >nul 2>&1" command to the prompt for each file in the directory, which is what causes my batch file to hang.

What do I need to change here?

Comment: What output do you see? What about if you remove the `>nul` part? Anyways, I'm pretty sure you need the /q (and possibly also the /f and /a) flag for `del`

Comment: I see `if not file.ext == UPDATE.BAT del /s file.ext >nul 2>&1` for every file in the directory.  I tried it without the `>nul` and that did not work either.

Comment: Even getting rid of the `/s` is not preventing it from outputting a command to the command line for every file found.

Comment: Your `/S` option is trying to delete in subdirectories, despite `%i` being relative only to a single level. I'd also suggest using `If /I Not "%i"=="UPDATE.BAT"` instead. If `UPDATE.BAT` is the name of your running script you can also change that to `"%~nx0"` to make that name not hard coded. Finally if you're using a batch file each instance of `%i` should be `%%i`.

Comment: The command is working correctly - it's just not suppressing the output to the command line, which is what's causing my batch file to stop.  Why is it still outputting a command for each file found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is directly in an open cmd window and not a batch,
you can suppres output of the current command with a leading `@` sign.

```
@for %i in (*) do @if /i not "%i"=="UPDATE.BAT" @del "%i" >nul 2>&1
```

In an batch toggle output of the commands with `@Echo off` and double the `%` signs of the for variable.

```
@Echo off
for %%i in (*) do if /i not "%%i"=="%~nx0" del "%%i" >nul 2>&1
```

Comment: The `/S` option is unlikely required in this case and the `/Q` option is definitely not required.

Comment: Well, the `@for %i in (*) do @if /i not "%i"=="%~nx0" @del /q /s "%i" >nul 2>&1` did work at the command line, but the `@Echo off
for %%i in (*) do if /i not "%i"=="%~nx0" del /q /s "%%i" >nul 2>&1` did not work in the batch script - still shows in the logs that it hangs at that command.

Comment: @BigRedEO missed to double one `%i` to `%%i` changed. Compo is right the /S /Q  dont' make sense.

Comment: As `>nul 2>&1` was used, I'm intrigued as to how your not mentioned previously logs show anything pertinent to the `del` command. Also, the command prompt code is wrong because the `"%~nx0"` notation will resolve to `""` so `"%i"` would never equal it.

Comment: I have a log for the entire batch script - just before each command, I send a comment with what is about to happen and a time stamp.  It always hangs at "about to delete extra files from the Download directory."  And I had already tried changing it to actually name the "UPDATE.BAT", but it still hung at the log entry just before this command was run.

Comment: @LotPings Thank you!  The missing `%` was what was causing the problem!  Just ran my update and it completed and did what I wanted!

Comment: Regardless of the fixed/edited command line version I stand by my first comment under this answer.

Comment: Sorry @compo, had too much windows open and at least one change got lost.